# What are commonly used price movement color schemes?

Tags: price

What are commonly used price movement color schemes?
Like 
American: up - green, down - red
European: up - blue, down - red
Asian 1: up - red, down - green
Asian 2: up - blue, down - red
Are these rules correct?

Comment: Correct on American and Chinese (=Asian 1), I don't know the others.

Comment: Wow - I always thought these were constant everywhere. I've even used green/red for positive/negative number display.